How to unblock XML files in outlook?
Blocked file
(https://i.sstatic.net/nltka.png)
Tried to find a solution to unblock a file in new Version of outlook (Microsoft Outlook Version 1.2024.403.300) but didn't find anything that will do the trick. In old version (Version 2403 Build 16.0.17425.20176 64-bit) it works just fine
